# Unable to disable smooth scrolling in react-scroll scrollToTop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smooth-scrolling, react-scroll

I am using the `react-scroll` library in order to handle scrolling on my React app. I want to scroll to the top whenever a specific button is clicked, however I do not want it to scroll smoothly, which seems to be enabled by default. I have tried the following code, however the page still scrolls smoothly, though the duration changed to 2 seconds successfully. I have tried other values for the `smooth` property, such as `easeInQuart`, etc., which worked perfectly. I tried putting `false` in quotes as well, to no avail.

```
<button onClick={() => animateScroll.scrollToTop({
      duration: 2000,
      smooth: false
    })}>
</button>
```

EDIT:

As Bronson pointed out below, the behavior is satisfied with the `window.scrollTo` method. To clarify, I was wondering why the code above does not display the same behavior, otherwise what point is there to accepting a `boolean` value for the `smooth` property if it is always enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just want to immediately take the user back to the top of the window? If so, you may want to just avoid using `react-scroll` here and just use the browser's [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) method instead:

```
<button onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0,0)}>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bronson. I am aware of the `window.scrollTo` method (which does work well for my use case), and perhaps my question wasn't as clear. I was wondering why it wasn't displaying the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS file write this code where ever you want,

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```